# "Do you not" vs. "Don't you"

Tags: word-order, questions, negation, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

I live in the UK and I mostly hear people saying *Don't you...*, but some people say: *Do you not...*? What is the difference and which one is more correct?

You can put any example really. Something like:

> Do you not like to come to school with me?
>   Don't you like to come to school with me?

Comment: In speech, negative interrogative contractions are fine. The other is only for emphasis: Do you **really** not like toast?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Both are correct. What was originally just a contraction of "do not" has become a word in itself, and can now be placed where the two separate words can't.

Both "Don't you..." and "Do you not..." are correct, but you can't re-expand "Don't you..." into "Do not you...".

The meaning of the two are the same, but "Do you not..." is considered more formal in some situations.

Comment: But I remember in a workshop about writing in academia, they said I should avoid using contracted forms. Does that mean that "Don't" would be incorrect in papers, or this is a special case?

Comment: *Do not you* is used in poetic language all the time. "But wherefore do not you a mightier way / 
Make war upon this bloody tyrant, Time?" — *Shakespeare, Sonnet 16*

Comment: In "standard" *spoken* English, "Don't you" is more common, and "do you not" sounds very formal. But in some UK dialects "do you not" is the more common form (and not considered formal).

Comment: @Rafid K. Abdullah: That depends on what you are writing. A scientific paper for example is quite formal, so contractions would usually look out of place there.

Comment: My sense is that American English prefers "don't" and "do you not" is a speech act with a peculiar meaning: "I am now interrogating and instructing you" in a Socratic fashion. On the other hand, "do you not" is fairly common Canadian usage with raising intonation on the 'not.'

Answer (score 0):

"Don't you like to come to school with me?" is a negative imperative sentence. It implies: "You want to come with me. Don't you?"

"Do you not like to come with me?" is more of a question either the audience wants to come with you or what ... I'm not sure about this one.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple present tense and an interrogative sentence.

Grammatically correct sentence structure for this is - (Do or Does + Subject + not + Verb + ...?).

Therefore, "Don't you?" has been considered as informal as well as incorrect.

And "Do you not?" is totally correct.

Answer (score -2):

"Do you not" is a self contradiction. It is the same as saying "do you" and "but you don't". It is completely redundant verbosity, which is a very common notion in British English vocabulary.