# Negative questions

Tags: negation, adverb-position, questions

I am in a trouble when I have to ask a question with negative verbs like:

1. Cannot we do the test?
2. Will not we do the test ?

Are the sentences above correct?

Comment: No, the sentences are not corrects. There are a lot of mistakes, but the specific [question you're asking about is answered here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/212765/15299).

Answer (score 1):

In the full form, put the negative just before the verb.

"Can we not do the test?"

"Will we not do the test?"

In the shortened form you can do:

"Can't we do the test?"

"Won't we do the test?"