# "What doesn't she know how to cook" vs. "What does not she know how to cook"

Tags: questions, do-support

Which of the following is correct? If A is correct why is B incorrect?

I am stumped, This sentence has popped up in my Hong Kong English class, don't know how to sort it out. Why does the one sentence sound awful yet is essentially the same:

> A) What doesn't she know how to cook?
>   B) What does not she know how to cook?
>   C) What does she not know how to cook?

Comment: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Negative-Interrogative-Sentences.htm

Comment: Related: [Why do not we ask negative questions without a contraction on the not after the verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212680/why-do-not-we-ask-negative-questions-without-a-contraction-on-the-not-after-the)

Comment: *What does she not know how to cook*.

Comment: Mr E, could you please either show the research you've done, or take that Question to English Language Learners, or both?