# General verb have with not

Tags: have

I got this sentence from the book of "At Lincoln's Side: John Hay's Civil War Correspondence and Selected Writings".

> There were few who had not a story worth listening to.

I think *did not have* is correct. Is *had not* available in a literary style?

Comment: Probably addressed by J Lawler at [Why do not we ask negative questions without ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212680/why-do-not-we-ask-negative-questions-without-a-contraction-on-the-not-after-the) .
<< ... If there is no auxiliary verb, a further rule gets involved:

Do-Support, the rule that supplies the auxiliary do to use with these rules.
(Auxiliary do carries the tense, so the main verb is changed to an infinitive)
In modern English Do-Support is obligatory; i.e, we can't ask questions like

*Slept you 8 hours yesterday?
any more. >> ...

Comment: Here, this is certainly archaic/literary style, and as such acceptable. 'Have' is the main verb (= 'possess', 'have with them'), not the auxiliary. // I'd say do-support isn't _quite_ obligatory nowadays; 'Have we not a duty to these people to ...' is acceptable, and 'rhetorical', almost 'epic', rather than 'literary' in register. [226 000 Google hits for "Have we not a duty to"]